# Change a labels for tag using Prototype?

Tags: prototypejs, label

I know I can change a labels id like this:

```
$(someid).id = 123;
```

How can I change the for, too?

This is the code I have:

```
<label id="10" for="xyz">
   sometext
</label>
```

How can I change the for from *xyz* to *abc* using Prototype?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(someid).writeAttribute('for', 'abc');

Comment: This worrks nice if I just have a static string, like abc. What if I have a dynamic string, like this:

`writeAttribute('for', 'options_' + someVar + '_2')`

This is not working, because the second param of the writeAttribute function has to be in quotes. How can I put that in quotes?

Comment: var concatenatedVar = 'options_' + someVar + '_2'; ....writeAttribute('for', concatenatedVar); maybe?